# Renaming default xmlns

Tags: xml, vb.net

This is the xml file that i generated:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--This document are generated by Apps. Please dont change any listed data here.-->
<q1:FilePenting xmlns:ksd="https://nerd.kekesed.id/xmlns/generic/v1" xmlns:q1="https://nerd.kekesed.id/xmlns/installer">
 <q1:Perpustakaan>
  <ksd:File PerluBanget="false">Ganteng</ksd:File>
  <ksd:File PerluBanget="false">Ganteng2</ksd:File>
 </q1:Perpustakaan>
</q1:FilePenting>
```

And i want to remove the `q1` things, it's really annoying T^T

Here's my classes:

```vb
<XmlRoot("FilePenting", Namespace:="https://nerd.kekesed.id/xmlns/installer")> _
Public Class RequiredFiles
    <XmlArray("Perpustakaan"), _
    XmlArrayItem("File", Namespace:="https://nerd.kekesed.id/xmlns/generic/v1")> _
    Public Libs() As Berkas

    <XmlNamespaceDeclarations()> _
    Public xmlns As New XmlSerializerNamespaces

    Sub New()
        xmlns.Add("ksd", "https://nerd.kekesed.id/xmlns/generic/v1")
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class Berkas
    <XmlText()> _
    Public NamaFile As String

    <XmlAttribute("version", namespace:="https://nerd.kekesed.id/xmlns/generic/v1")> _
    Public VersiFile As String

    <XmlAttribute("PerluBanget")> _
    Public PerluBanget As Boolean = False

    Sub New()

    End Sub
End Class
```

And this is the serializer code:

```vb
Private Sub Button_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    Dim FileBrow As New Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog
    With FileBrow
        .Title = "Init XML Save File"
        .Filter = "XML File (*.xml)|*.xml"

        .ShowDialog()
        If Not .FileName Is Nothing Then
            'mulai bikin objek dan save dan lain lain lain lain
            Dim x As New IsiSetup.RequiredFiles()
            x.Libs = {New Berkas() With {.NamaFile = "Ganteng"}, New Berkas() With {.NamaFile = "Ganteng2"}}

            Dim Aturannya As New XmlWriterSettings() With {.Indent = True, .IndentChars = " ", .NewLineChars = vbNewLine}

            Dim penulis As New XmlSerializer(x.GetType)
            Dim Xmlnya As XmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(.FileName, Aturannya)
            Xmlnya.WriteComment("This document are generated by Apps. Please dont change any listed data here.")

            Dim Ns As New XmlSerializerNamespaces()
            Ns.Add("", "")

            penulis.Serialize(Xmlnya, x, Ns)
            'done

            Xmlnya.Close()
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

I wanted to remove the default xmlns like w3c etc thing, and adding the default xmlns to the root.

How to do it without giving out `q1` named xmlns? I mean, i want it to be `xmlns="https://nerd.kekesed.id/xmlns/installer"`.

**Update**

I didn't want it to be declared from outside of the class. As i want to declare it on many projects, so, declaring outside from the class is not a clean solution.

Thank you!

Comment: Try setting `Ns.Add("", "https://nerd.kekesed.id/xmlns/installer")`.

Comment: ahh i forgot to mention that i don't want it declared from the outside of class. It wont be constant everytime i need to declare the class ._.

Comment: Why do you care about what prefix is being used? It doesn't change the *information content* of the file one bit.

Comment: i just want it looks pretty, that's it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by adding the class's Xmlns when serializing it.

```vb
penulis.Serialize(Xmlnya, x, x.xmlns)
```

And, don't forget to declare the Xmlns first with no prefixes on the **root** and the `XmlNamespaceDeclarations()` ~

```
<XmlRoot("FilePenting", Namespace:="https://nerd.kekesed.id/xmlns/installer")> _
Public Class RequiredFiles

    <XmlArray("Perpustakaan"), _
    XmlArrayItem("File", Namespace:="https://nerd.kekesed.id/xmlns/generic/v1")> _
    Public Libs() As Berkas

    <XmlElement("Provider")> _
    Public Vendor As Provider

    <XmlNamespaceDeclarations()> _
    Public xmlns As New XmlSerializerNamespaces

    Sub New()
        xmlns.Add("", "https://nerd.kekesed.id/xmlns/installer")
        xmlns.Add("ksd", "https://nerd.kekesed.id/xmlns/generic/v1")
    End Sub
End Class
```

and this is what i wanted it looks like :3

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--This document are generated by Apps. Please dont change any listed data here.-->
<FilePenting xmlns:ksd="https://nerd.kekesed.id/xmlns/generic/v1" xmlns="https://nerd.kekesed.id/xmlns/installer">
  <Perpustakaan>
    <ksd:File PerluBanget="false" Tipe="Liblari">Ganteng</ksd:File>
    <ksd:File PerluBanget="false" Tipe="Liblari">Ganteng2</ksd:File>
  </Perpustakaan>
</FilePenting>
```

Isn't it looks pretty? >.<